# Having problem while scraping Klaytn Scope Table

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have some problems while I scrape 'https://scope.klaytn.com/account/0xb5471a00bcc02ea297df2c4a4fd1d073465c662b?tabId=tokenBalance'

this website using python with bs4, requests.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
import urllib3
import pandas as pd
urllib3.disable_warnings()
```

I want to scrape Token Balance Table, so I requests, but nothing respond.

Klaytn Scope

[image]

How can I scrape this 'Token Balnace' Table Value?

When I use 'find' method to find all of the table value, but it prints 'None'.

```
html = requests.get(url, verify=False).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
title = soup.find('span', {'class': 'ValueWithUnit__value'})

print(title)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page is generated using the API. For example, a table is obtained from the following address: https://api-cypress-v3.scope.klaytn.com/v2/accounts/0xb5471a00bcc02ea297df2c4a4fd1d073465c662b/ftBalances?page=1

Account info: https://api-cypress-v3.scope.klaytn.com/v2/accounts/0xb5471a00bcc02ea297df2c4a4fd1d073465c662b

So u can get table:

```
url = 'https://api-cypress-v3.scope.klaytn.com/v2/accounts/0xb5471a00bcc02ea297df2c4a4fd1d073465c662b/ftBalances?page=1'
response = requests.get(url)
for token in response.json()['tokens']:
    tokenName = response.json()['tokens'][token]['tokenName']
    tokenAmount = next(amount['amount'] for amount in response.json()['result'] if amount['tokenAddress'] == token)
    print(tokenName, tokenAmount)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Ironscale 128
Bloater 158
Lantern-Eye 144
Gaia's Tears 101
Redgill 11
...
Blue Egg 1
Green Egg 1
Health Vial 1
Mana Vial 1
```